# Spring Batch to process multiple Items at once

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, bulk

We are using Spring Batch to do some processing, reading some ids via Reader and we want to process them as 'chunks' via a processor then write to multiple files. But the processor interface allows only one item to processed at a time, we need to do bulk processing because the processor depends on a third party and calling the service for each item is not an option.

I saw that we can create Wrappers for all Reader-Processor-Writers involved in the 'chunk' to handle List<> and delegate to some concrete reader/processor/writer. but that doesn't seem all nice to me. Like this:

```
   <batch:chunk reader="wrappedReader" processor="wrappedProcessor" writer="wrappedWriter" 
commit-interval="2"/>
```

Is there a 'chunking' option that lets chunking before the processor? rather than before Writer.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend reconfiguring your `ItemReader` to return the "chunk" that needs to be processed since that's really the "item" you're processing is.

Comment: yeah at the end we wrote some wrappers for ItemReader that returns chunks, and for ItemWriter that can handle chunks in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Since modifying the whole Spring Batch mechanic to process multiple items at once seems really complicated, I suggest you move your third party processing to a writer which actually can process a chunk of item at once.

Since you'll obviously need to maintain your current writer, you could simply use a `CompositeItemWriter` with 2 (or more) delegates : your new custom `ItemWriter` and your current one. The order of definition matters, since it will be the order in which they'll be called.

---

**UPDATE**

Since using 2 distinct `ItemWriter` inside a `CompositeItemWriter` doesn't let you keep the modifications of the first one in the second one, you could also use an `ItemWriteListener`.

By implementing the method `beforeWrite`, you can call your third party with the actual chunk right before it's written :

```
@Override
public void beforeWrite(List<? extends T> items) {
    //Third party call on item chunk
}
```

Comment: do you mean CompositeItemWriter? since you can't add a ItemWriter to CompositeItemProcessor. maybe we can do a Custom ItemWriter that will do the thirdparty call as you mentioned along with a 'ItemWriter' delegate, so that we can pass the result to delegate after the thirdparty call. still not a nice solution given that our 'business logic' should be in processor.

Comment: @tonakai Yes, I meant "writer". And you're also right concerning the delegate inside the custom writer, if you need the result of the third party to be written. Otherwise the composite will simply write the item in its state post-processing, without the previous results.

Comment: @tonakai I updated my answer with another solution, considering your need to save the item modification resulting from third party call.

Comment: regarding the update, yeah that seems like another solution, but this time we need to modify the return type of my Reader to match with the third-party call's return type, then I can modify the content of the list without much problem.